# How to fire command when page is shown

Tags: c#, wpf, mvvm

This is my scenario.

I have a `MainWindow` with a `frame`. This frame allows me to navigate from `Page1` to `Page2` to `Page3` (in any order).

What I need is; When each page is displayed, I need a command to be fired

For instance:

My 3 pages all have `DataGrids`.

```
mc:Ignorable="d"
  Title="Page1">

<DataGrid DataContext="{Binding Source={x:Static VM:ViewModel.Instance}}"
          ItemsSource="{Binding CustomerCollection, Mode=TwoWay, UpdateSourceTrigger=PropertyChanged}"
          RowDetailsVisibilityMode="VisibleWhenSelected"
          AutoGenerateColumns="True">

</DataGrid>
```

These DataGrids are bound to the same 'Customer' `ObservableCollection` in the same `(static)` `ViewModel`.

```
    public ObservableCollection<customer> CustomerCollection
    {
        get
        {
            return _customercollection;
        }
        set
        {
            _customercollection = value;
            OnPropertyChanged("CustomerCollection");
        }
    }
```

This means that at any given point in time, each page shows the same `Customer` information.

Now I want `Page1` to show **active Customers**, `Page2` to show **suspended Customers**, and `Page3` to show **resigned Customers**.

I need to fire different query in the `ViewModel` for each page. Each query is specific to **page**.

**But how do I get this query to fire automatically as I navigate from page to page?**

> The idea here is to limit how much memory is in use when the
>   application runs by recycling the same `ObservableCollections`.

Comment: Introduce a new property that is bound to the current page index; then when that property is updated by the view (the setter is called on the view model), you update the collectioin.

Comment: Do you have also a VM for your Page? I think you should have that if none yet.

Comment: @poke The concept makes sense. But I'm having a bit of difficulty finding sources on 'current page index'. Think you could point one out? Google doesn't seem to be too helpful in that regard.

Comment: @tagaPdyk You mean specifically for the page I'm using? Then no. The only VM I have is shared by all three pages. How would a dedicated one for one view help if I may ask?

Comment: @Offer You could maybe use [`CurrentSource`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.controls.frame.currentsource.aspx) or [`Source`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.controls.frame.source.aspx) to identify the current page.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I think you can bind a command to loaded event to each page and pass a command parameter ,depending upon than you can select your observable collection.

```
<Window x:Class="V_Parcel.SplashPage"
        xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml/presentation"
        xmlns:x="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml"
        xmlns:CommandClass="clr-namespace:V_Parcel"
        xmlns:prop="clr-namespace:V_Parcel.Properties"
        xmlns:vm="clr-namespace:V_Parcel"     
        xmlns:i="clr-namespace:System.Windows.Interactivity;assembly=System.Windows.Interactivity"
       >
    <i:Interaction.Triggers>
        <i:EventTrigger EventName="Loaded">
            <i:InvokeCommandAction Command="{Binding StartButton}" CommandParameter="1" />
        </i:EventTrigger>
    </i:Interaction.Triggers>
```

Answer (score 2):

View model is a thing, that prepares data to be easily displayed in a view.
You need a filtered data - so, do the filtering somewhere in view model.

One way is to hide `CustomerCollection` and make [collection views](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.componentmodel.icollectionview%28v=vs.110%29.aspx) in the same view model (but it would be better to hold a separate view model per page):

```
public class ViewModel
{
    private ObservableCollection<Customer> _customercollection;

    private void LoadCustomers()
    {
        _customercollection = // load customers somehow;
        ActiveCustomers = new ListCollectionView(_customercollection)
        {
            Filter = c => ((Customer)c).IsActive
        };
        OnPropertyChanged("ActiveCustomers");

        // almost the same code for SuspendedCustomers and ResignedCustomers
    }

    public ICollectionView ActiveCustomers { get; private set; }
    private ICollectionView SuspendedCustomers { get; private set; }
    private ICollectionView ResignedCustomers { get; private set; }

    // rest of code
}
```

XAML:

```
<DataGrid ItemsSource="{Binding ActiveCustomers}"/>
```

Note, that you can make these properties using lazy initialization (thus, create appropriate collection view on demand).

Comment: Ironically it was this solution I implemented. I had to give Justin CI his credit though. His solution did do exactly what I asked and I didn't want this question to be misleading for the next person to come along. Much gratitude Dennis. I learnt a lot thanks to this.

Answer (score 0):

You can use the events on [NavigationService](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.navigation.navigationservice%28v=vs.110%29.aspx) to setup your viewmodel. More - and better - information on NavigationService here: http://paulstovell.com/blog/wpf-navigation

You could also try to put a Converter on each ItemSource that filters your collection.

Comment: You should expand this answer a bit further.

Comment: I went to the definition and I can grasp the concept but I'm not all that sure how to implement that in my case. Any examples?